# Is the set $\{\frac{p}{q}:p,q\text{ prime}\}$ dense in the positive real numbers?

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, prime-numbers, real-numbers

If $P$ is the set of all prime numbers, and we denote by $Q$ the set of all rationals which are of the form $\frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ and $q$ are both are prime numbers, then is $Q$ dense in set of positive real numbers?

I think not, since prime numbers are not uniformly distributed in the set of positive integers, but I can't  prove it.

Whereas I can prove that the set of rationals $\frac{m}{p}$, where $p$ is prime, is dense in positive reals.

Comment: Another duplicate (though with no answer, so it should also be closed as a duplicate of the one linked to above): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/255389/264

Comment: I recently saw a paper in one of the MAA journals which showed that $p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are Gaussian primes is dense in the plane.

Comment: yes, i see the above link, and it solve my problem, thenks

Comment: but i don't get how p/q are dense on plane, as said by marty cohen

Comment: @NishiAcherjo, Gaussian primes are primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. So, $p/q$ is a complex number.